# How do I make my character move diagonally in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard-events

I'm having trouble making my figure move diagonally with the arrowkeys. I can make it so that it moves up, down, left and right but I'm unsure how to make it read that two buttons are pressed down at once and therefore it should move in a certain way. This it the code I have for the keypresses so far. Any tips are appreciated!

```
function keyPressHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        switch( event.keyCode )
        {
            case Keyboard.UP:
                up = true;
                beetle_mc.rotation = 0;
                beetle_mc.y -=speed;
                up_mc.gotoAndStop(2);
                break;
                
            case Keyboard.DOWN:
                down = true;
                beetle_mc.rotation = 180;
                beetle_mc.y +=speed;
                down_mc.gotoAndStop(2);
                break;
                
            case Keyboard.LEFT:
                left = true;
                beetle_mc.rotation = 270;
                beetle_mc.x -=speed;
                left_mc.gotoAndStop(2);
                break;
                
            case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                right = true;
                beetle_mc.rotation = 90;
                beetle_mc.x +=speed;
                right_mc.gotoAndStop(2);
                break;
```

Comment: Try to `trace` (console log) the key code before doing `switch( event.keyCode )`. What feedback does compiler give when you press 2 keys at once (doing a diagonal input)?

Comment: You shuold separate key handling with movement processing logic. This would allow you to read input like "both right and down is true" and have a branch of code making up for that. Remember also to set those vars to false at key release.